# What is the interpretation of this code

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain in the simplest terms, as if you are talking to an idiot (because you are), what this code is actually saying/doing/meaning?

```
var i = 5;
while(--i > 0){
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: --i will decrement the value of i by 1 before the condition is checked. So the first console.log(i) will print 4

Comment: I can see something like 8 different, basic JavaScript concepts in that code. Which bit don't you understand and haven't been able to find out about in the documentation?

Comment: Can you explain which exact part you don't understand since all of that is covered by basic tutorials?

Comment: I Think he doesnt understand the --i part

Comment: We would like the OP to state that in the question since that is why users are provided a "Question" section to ask questions.

Comment: your questions record is obviously not good, so please consider reading the documentation prior to posting questions.

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt — What makes you think it is that part, rather then one of the 7 other basic parts of JS expressed in that code, that they don't understand?

Comment: This question and the answers make me wish I had more votes left today.

Comment: I'm really curious as to which two people clicked the up arrow marked "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"

Comment: @Quentin Just guessing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a basic tutorial service.

Comment: Any yet sadly we found 4 (was 5) spoon feeders anyway... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable `i` and store the value 5 into it.

`--i` means to decrement `i` by one, then return the value of `i` (note this is different from `i--`, which means to return `i`, THEN decrement it). So to say `--i > 0` means, reduce `i` by one, and only continue executing the `while` loop while it's greater than 0. Each iteration of the loop then prints the value of `i`.

So your output will be:

```
4 
3 
2 
1
```

5 is skipped because `i` is reduced by one when the loop starts, and `0` can't be evaluated because it fails `0 > 0`. If the loop condition had been `i-- > 0`, then you would see `0` in your output.

EDIT: I should note that this syntax makes it difficult in quickly evaluating how the code will behave. You can loop from 4 to 1 in a manner that is much more concise:

```
var i = 4;
while(i >= 1) {
  console.log(i);
  i--; // or i -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define a number variable `i` with an integer value of `5`.

while `i` is greater than `0`: output the value of `i` to the console.

the `--i` is subtracting 1 from `i`, but the new value is used in the condition.
if the line was `i--` then the value of i before 1 is subtracted would be the value in the condition.

Answer (score -1):

First `i` is equal to 5, and then 1 is subtracted from `i`, and now `i` is equal to 4. 1 is subsequently subtracted from `i` until `i` is equal to 0. The loop is then exited when `i == 0`. The output should be 4 3 2 1.